# How to use the ng-material in angular 2?

Tags: angular, nodes

In my application I have some controls like checkbox, menu button
etc. Now I want to use the `ng-material` design for Angular 2. So
what steps should I follow to implement Angular 2 Material?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the angular2/material project, the best route is to follow the official project [guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

There is also the [ng2-material](https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/#/) project.

Comment: I know these link I want to add the angular 2 material by using visual studio 2015 , if know the step then please share it.